# Hide Delete button from UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

- When my table view is in edit mode, the red (-) buttons appear.
- When the user taps one of them the [Delete] button appears.
- When the user taps on [Delete] I first check a few things (partly online).  This delete may not be allowed.
- When deleting that cell is not allowed, how do I hide the [Delete] button and let the red (|) button become a (-) again in an animated way?  So, I don't want my whole table to leave editing state.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Do you need to allow any editing at all?  Sounds like you just need to disable edit mode and your problem is solved.  Try:  [self setEditing:NO animated:YES] (where 'self' is your UITableView instance)

Comment: @AbdullahShafique I'm using a `NSFetchedResultsController` and would have to post non-related code.  The deletion process described is mainly handled by the `UITableView`.

Comment: @MystikSpiral No. A user may want to delete another cell as well, and I don't want to force him having to tap Edit on the navbar again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the actual animation (Instead of the `UITableViewRowAnimationRight`/`UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic`) animations, just do

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:NO];
[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:NO];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

`beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` provide the animation, and the tableView is just switched from not editing to editing instantly, which closes the delete button.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This answer is incorrect but because you suggest using `setEditing` I've selected it as 'the' answer.  Here's what the answer should have been: `[self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];`; yes, just that.  No idea why you set `animated` to `NO`, why you set the table back to editing mode again, and the `begin/endUpdates` are not needed to get the animation as [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/setEditing:animated:) explains.

Comment: This works for me. I was trying to call it though inside commitEditingStyle and it wasn't working there. I used a dispatch.async to tableView.setEditing(false, animated: false) tableView.setEditing(true, animated: false). That works to animate the row back to the state with the Delete button hidden. beginUpdates()/endUpdates() weren't needed. On iOS 10.

Answer (score 7):

I've run into this issue myself where I may bring up an alert view to prompt the user further and wish to reset the delete button if they choose not to proceed.  This seems like the easiest approach, assuming *deleteIndexPath* is the index path of the row selected for deletion:

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[deleteIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for the OP question - a better example would be user taps delete, program generates actionSheet to confirm, user cancels out.  Also better to use UITableViewRowAnimationRight as this is opposite of motion when delete button appears.

Answer (score 1):

I now see that you want to disable delete for only certain cells.  You can do this in a couple of ways:

`tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath` method:  Return NO where you want DELETES to be DISABLED.
`tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath`:  Return YES where you want to allow reordering.

You may want to think about sub-classing UITableViewCell to give it some ability to maintain its own state (so the cell knows if delete is allowed or not.  Then you can interrogate the actual cell instance and determine if you should enable delete even after the list may be re-ordered.

Comment: I did not say that I wanted to "disable" delete for certain cells.  I want to "hide" an already shown [Delete] button.  Please tell me what you are missing in my question for you to understand correctly!

Comment: I think you are looking at this from the wrong angle.  I am trying to give you a sample that will prevent the delete button from ever showing at all.  If you are intentionally trying to show then hide a delete button with animation, that is just going to confuse users.  If you do not want the users to delete, never show the button at all, then you have nothing to hide.  Without some code (or a real use case) I am not sure I can help any more.

Comment: I agree with @MystikSpiral that what you're doing seems confusing for users. Better to indicate on the cells themselves by preventing them being editable. I don't agree with making a subclass of UITableViewCell so the cell can know if it's delete-able or not however - it has no place knowing that. Your underlying data model should be capable of holding this information, and changing the view to reflect this then becomes trivial.

Comment: @MystikSpiral The point is that I don't know beforehand which deletes of cells will fail or succeed.  Also, generally speaking, it can be bad for users to have delete buttons show up on some, but not all cells without giving a reason; having a delete button is a way to give users the reason of why a delete is not possible.

Comment: @WillJenkins It's nice that you agree with MS :-)  But, please see my comment above.

Comment: Well in that case, if you're only trying to setEditing of one cell, this answer would appear to be what you're after: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2742445/93812

Comment: @MystikSpiral I've tried this, because in some cases I do know beforehand, but then in edit more the table looks really weird: Some row are shifted to the right and have the red (-), while others don't.  Is there a standard way to get all rows shifted, or some other way to deal with mixed yes/no can delete rows?

Comment: @WillJenkins Yes, I saw the `setEditing` too, but when set to NO, the row shifts back to the left and the (-) disappears; this gives a really ugly sight with some rows indented, while others don't (see above comment as well).

Comment: @MystikSpiral I ended up not allowing the red (-) to appear, and only show the [Delete] after swipe when actually deletable.  I then will also create a Delete cell button in the detail view for items that can be deleted, for the others I'll place a section footer explaining why.  Then when deletion still won't be possible (after accessing my server), I will show a pop-up.  Doing all this will avoid weird stuff in the UI.  Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 1):

To hide any icon in whole table view, then in your controller just ,
override EditingStyleForRow and return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.None

1. None: will hide any icon of left of items of table view,
2. delete: will show remove icon
3. Insert: will show add icon