# How to hide "Delete" button of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

When my tableview is in edit mode ,cells show "-" button. 
When users tap "-" button,cell will show a "Delete" button.
I don't want this "Delete" button,how can I prevent it showing from right.I want immediately delete that row when users tap "-" button.

Comment: Post some code how you are trying?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide Delete button from UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18697356/hide-delete-button-from-uitableviewcell)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18697356/1142743 this has answer

Comment: I added a custom delete button in cell and set cell's edittingstyle to none,when tableview is editing,the button appears with animate, I can directly handle the action when users tap the button and delete the cell.Problem solved.